# Convert Spark's DataFrame to RDD[Vector]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

When I was trying to convert a Spark's `DataFrame` into `RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]` using the following code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
  Seq((0.1, 0.2, 0.4))
).toDF("t1", "t2", "t3")

df.rdd.map{ case Row(row: Seq[_]) =>
  Vectors.dense(row.asInstanceOf[Seq[Double]].toArray)
}.collect
```

I got a error message like this:

```
scala.MatchError: [0.1,0.2,0.4] (of class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema)
```

Then I tried another method:

```
df.content.rdd.map{ case row =>
  Vectors.dense(row.toSeq.toArray.map{
    x => x.asInstanceOf[Double]
  })
}.collect
```

It worked out fine.

While the first method was introduced in the [official version of Spark-2.2.0-SNAPSHOT](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/51b1c1551d3a7147403b9e821fcc7c8f57b4824c/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/recommendation/MatrixFactorizationModel.scala#L373) when converting `row` into `Array[Double]`, it did not work.

Can anyone figure out the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two methods don't do the same thing. In the first case you're trying to match against a `Row` with a single `ArrayType` column. Since your input contains three columns the `MatchException` is an expected outcome. This could work only if you gather columns as an array, for example

```
df.select(array(df.columns.map(col(_)): _*)).rdd.map { 
  case Row(xs: Seq[Double @unchecked]) => xs 
}
```

or

```
df.select(array(df.columns.map(col(_)): _*)).rdd.map(_.getSeq[Double](0))
```

In the second case you are converting row to `Seq[Any]` which gives you a sequence of field values.